# Can I make a statement with two WHEREs and value of second where coming from 3rd table?

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have 3 tables. First one is users, with different users on it. Second one has posts on it, with posters ID from table1 and the contents of the post.

Third table has the friendslist. In the form of:

```
+------------+----------+
| userID | friendID |
+------------+----------+
|          4 |        3 |
|          3 |        4 |
|          1 |        3 |
|          3 |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

Now what I am trying to figure out is how to make it so that when user1 looks at the posts he only sees the posts of only his friends.

I got as far as creating this:

`SELECT posts.IDpost, users.name, posts.created, posts.content FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id=posts.poster WHERE posts.poster= ?`

I figured I would have to add something like this:

```
WHERE friendslist.user= user1;
```

But I can't figure out how to add it, tried google searching for it with no luck, I don't know if I simply can't figure out how to search for it or it is not possible. I probably have to use a JOIN at the end there, but again, I'm not sure how.
So how could I join values from 3 tables, with 2 WHERE commands?
Hope someone understands my question and is able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT posts.IDpost, users.name, posts.created, posts.content 
  FROM users 
      JOIN posts 
          ON users.id=posts.poster 
  WHERE posts.poster in (
         SELECT  friendID
         FROM    friendslist
         WHERE   userID = user1  -- This would be the ID of the user you're querying for.
       )
```

That's SQL Server syntax, but the idea should be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Also learned something new. Happy to see I was going in the right-ish direction. :)

Comment: Since you aren´t using any specific functions this is ANSI SQL'99 and will work in any database that follow this standards which is pretty much all of then. :)